# Consolidate Similar SCSS Classes

Tags: css, sass

I have two sets of 48 classes that all have similar structure, and I was wondering if there was an elegant way to consolidate them in SCSS.

The first set follows this pattern

It's repeated up to Twelve Columns, each time the width going up by 1/12. The margins stay the same. Then the entire structure of twelve columns is repeated 4 times, one for xsmall, small, medium, and large. The only differences here are class name so

```
.largeOneColumn {
    width: calc(8.33% - #{$column-spacing}) !important;
    margin-left: $column-margins !important;
    margin-right: $column-margins !important;
}
```

would be an example.

The second set is

```
.col-xsmall-offSet-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
.col-xsmall-offSet-11 {
    left: 91.66%;
  }
```

Same general idea, decrements to 1, which reduces `left:` by 1/12 each time. Then repeated 4 times across xsmall, small, medium, large.

I was hoping to use some SCSS to make all this more elegant and condensed, instead of needing to repeat so much code.

Thanks!

Comment: I think foundation6 have some cool scss functions/mixins to set the columns and stuff more pretty. You might find something in their source code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of SASS lists and loops you should be able to do this fairly easily. They can be nested if need be.

https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists/

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

I've used these patterns repeatedly as a basis for creating incremented CSS like you're trying to do. Let us know how it goes or if you need more help.